# Change language in Bootstrap form feedback?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have created a Swedish login page using Bootstrap 4. The input fields are required. So if the user tries to "Login" with empty fields, a feedback message is shown in English (see the picture below).

Is it possible to customize or override the message and provide the feedback in Swedish instead?

[image: Enlgish feedback message]

Answer (score 2):

with the oninvalid feature, you can give the desired warning.

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" 
        oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('any article you want can come here.')">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```